# SQL - How to SUM columns from 3 other Queries

Tags: sql, ms-access, sum

I want to total 3 columns in 3 Tables generated from Queries. The three tables are Payroll_Table, Misc_Table, Depreciation_Table. Each table has Store_ID and Payroll_Expense or Misc_Expense or Depreciation_Expense columns.

I am trying to obtain the total of Payroll, Misc, and Depreciation for each Store_ID.

```
SELECT Store_ID, SUM(Payroll_Expense + Misc_Expense + Depreciation_Expense) AS Total
FROM (
SELECT Store_ID, Payroll_Expense FROM [Payroll_Table]UNION ALL
SELECT Store_ID, Misc_Expense AS FROM [Misc_Table] UNION ALL
SELECT Store_ID, Depreciation_Expense FROM [Depreciation_Table]
)
GROUP BY Store_ID
```

If I run this query, I get a prompt to 'Enter Parameter Value' for Misc_Expense and Depreciation_Expense. If I enter 1, I get the correct value but I am unsure why I get this prompt.

Comment: The union all isn't doing what you think it is... The only columns coming out of the derrived table is payroll_expense and store_ID.

Comment: oh and if you enter 1 for both, you're inflating your sum per store by 2. if you entered 0; then it would be correct (if you just wanted payroll_expense total).  It's treating those columns as variables which you defined a constant of 1 twice.  so X+1+1 is going to be two bigger than the payroll expense but short the Misc_expense and depreciation_expenses you're after.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the union is generating only two columns store_ID and "Expense" (Actually Payroll_Expense)

The system doesn't know what misc_expense and depreciation_expense are; which is why you get prompted for both. This can be seen if you do a select * from your derived table as follows:

```
SELECT * 
FROM (
SELECT Store_ID, Payroll_Expense Expense FROM [Payroll_Table]UNION ALL
SELECT Store_ID, Misc_Expense FROM [Misc_Table] UNION ALL
SELECT Store_ID, Depreciation_Expense FROM [Depreciation_Table]
) DerivedTable
```

So based on this you can see there isn't a MISC_EXPENSE column and a Depreciation_Expense; they are all rolled into Payroll_Expense (Expense). So the derived table has only 2 columns, not the 4 you were expecting by your outer select.  We could still get 4; you just have to use option 2 below; but is it needed?

**To resolve:** 
Simply omit Misc_Expense and Depreciation_Expense in your outer query as they are in the "Expense" column as a result of the and alias the column for posterity.

The column names and data types for each column in a union are inherited from the column names and data types of the first query; unless, null, then it's the first data type encountered.

**So we can just do this:**

```
SELECT Store_ID, SUM(Expense) AS Total
FROM (
SELECT Store_ID, Payroll_Expense AS Expense FROM [Payroll_Table]UNION ALL
SELECT Store_ID, Misc_Expense FROM [Misc_Table] UNION ALL
SELECT Store_ID, Depreciation_Expense FROM [Depreciation_Table]
) as DerivedTable
GROUP BY Store_ID
```

If for some reason you still need all 3 columns then you need placeholders for the other two columns. (OPTION 2)

```
SELECT Store_ID, SUM(Payroll_Expense + Misc_Expense + Depreciation_Expense) AS Total
FROM (
SELECT Store_ID
     , Payroll_Expense
     , NULL as Misc_expense
     , Null as Depreciation_expense 
FROM [Payroll_Table] UNION ALL
SELECT Store_ID
     , NULL as Payroll_Expense
     , Misc_Expense
     , Null as Depreciation_expense
FROM [Misc_Table] UNION ALL
SELECT Store_ID
     , Null as Payroll_expense
     , Null as Misc_expense
     , Depreciation_Expense 
FROM [Depreciation_Table]
) as DerivedTable
GROUP BY Store_ID
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't refer to different column names when you `UNION` you should refer to the index/position of the column or alias the columns like this:

```
SELECT Store_ID, SUM(Expense) AS Total
FROM (
SELECT Store_ID, Payroll_Expense AS [Expense] FROM [Payroll_Table]UNION ALL
SELECT Store_ID, Misc_Expense AS [Expense] FROM [Misc_Table] UNION ALL
SELECT Store_ID, Depreciation_Expense AS [Expense] FROM [Depreciation_Table]
)
GROUP BY Store_ID
```